# Java health monitoring in clustered environment

Tags: java, rest, hazelcast, distributed-system, health-monitoring

I am working on back end service, which is running in clustered environment (running  three instance in parallel to distribute some calculation job). I am using hazel cast for creating cluster and distributing jobs.

I want to create rest end point to do some health checks of the service. As this service is in clustering mode, i need to check health check in all instances.

How would i achieve this kind of health check across cluster? 
Is there any library available which is recommended for this?

Comment: do you expose any healtcheck service in your application or do you want to rely on Hazelcast's healtcheck service?

Comment: I want rest end point for healthcheck which should provide not only hazelcast related heathcheck but also other internal business related checks. but want this accross cluster.

Comment: I understand. I don't know of any distributed healthcheck library or tool. But for Hazelcast side this could be useful for you: https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#health-check

Comment: As far as I understand you want a tool that will aggregate the health check results of each instance and report it in a unified way, right?

Comment: yes. @OzanKılıç. exactly. not only health check(like cpu, memory etc) but also some internal business functional check

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to “push” health indicators to a db (all instances need to know or “discover” the db).

Another approach is to use consul (or similar solutions) to register services with health checks.
Consul has a few java clients you can choose from.

Answer (score 0):

Java platform has [JMX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/index.html) feature, you need to implement JMX beans for your services which will provide application metrics. Then you can use one of the existing solutions to monitor JMX metrics (Zabbiz, Grafana, ELK etc.) or implement your own service which will poll or consumes JMX data from the each instance in your cluseter and provide access to this data via rest api.